# Symfony module not redirecting

Tags: symfony1

i developed a module from here http://www.symfony-project.org/askeet/1_0/en/2
but when i access it from http://askeet/contact it says Object not found!

Comment: Can I ask why you're doing a Symfony 1.0 tutorial? Symfony 1.4 (with its corresponding [Jobeet](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/) rather than Askeet tutorial) is the current version...

Comment: I just searched tutorial for Symfony and got that..... Can you please tell me why this is happening? beacause everything went fine on the command line until i ran it on the browser.

Comment: As Matt says, Symfony 1.0 is way out of date. If you're just starting a project, ditch it and use Symfony 1.4 instead.

Comment: i m doing it just for learning ...

Comment: @user418232: Do you mean you're willing to learn how to code with Symfony **1.0** ? O_o

Comment: Don't go through a tutorial for a framework that nobody uses anymore.

Comment: In our OP's defence, I imagine this isn't helped by the fact that virtually every Google search for anything to do with Symfony ends up dumping you at the 1.0 documentation at symfony-project.org. Nevertheless, @user418232, I recommend you start again, with version 1.4. There have been enough changes and fixes that 1.0 is really *not* what you want to be learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you were already told in the commands, do not learn symfony 1.0.

The most probable solution for your problem: you do not have mod_rewrite enabled for your virtualhost. Make sure you both enable it as an apache module and in your VH configuration.